# Regular Expression matching anything after a word

Tags: regex

I am looking to find anything that matches this pattern, the beginning word will be:

```
organism aogikgoi egopetkgeopt foprkgeroptk 13
```

So anything that starts with `organism` needs to be found using regex.

Comment: Err, `^organism`? What exactly are you trying to do? Any language can find it without a regex... What language are you using? Is it always the start of the line? Should you filter these lines from other lines?

Comment: Which language or type of regexes are you using?

Comment: This is for google analytics.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`^organism` will match anything starting with "organism".

`^organism(.*)` will also capture everything that follows, into the variable that contains the first match (which varies according to language -- in Perl it's `$1`).

Comment: I recommend adding `$` to the end. Its easier to read that way (although its a very simple regexp).

Answer (score 0):

Also just wanna add for others newbies like me and their various circumstances, you can do it in various ways depending on your text and what you are tryna do.

Like here's an [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f54Om.jpg) where I wanna delete everything after **?spam** so I could use **.?spm.+** or **.?spm.+** or any other ways as long you are creative about it lol.

This might come in handy, here's a [Link](https://github.com/CoreyMSchafer/code_snippets/blob/master/Regular-Expressions/snippets.txt) | [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20220920061914/https://github.com/CoreyMSchafer/code_snippets/blob/master/Regular-Expressions/snippets.txt) where you can find some basic necessary regex and their meanings.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30917781)